# Modify JSTL import tag to show gzipped text in JSP

Tags: java, gzip, jstl, compression

In my JSPs I am currently using JSTL to show the contents of simple text files that reside on a server as follows:

c:import url="http://www.mysite.com/texts/name_id.txt" charEncoding="UTF-8"/>

These text files can be quite long and there are many of them so I want to compress them and serve the compressed version to the import tag. Can you give me some suggestions on how to modify the JSTL import tag, or create my own tag that achieves the same result when the text file is compressed? I suspect I should use Apache Commons Codec, or is java.util.zip enough?

For your reference, the source for the JSTL 1.2 import tag can be seen at:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/rt/core/ImportTag.java

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ImportSupport.java#ImportSupport

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a servlet which is mapped on an URL pattern of `/texts/*` and does roughly the following job in `doGet()`.

```
String path = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length());
InputStream input = new GzipInputStream(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(path));
OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
// Write input to output.
```

Note that the URL is based on your question and that you can keep your URLs in JSP unchanged this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I actually need is to supply the contents of this compressed text file only within one div inside my page. The rest of the content comes from the JSP and Struts framework. This is why I was looking at using a tag similar to the JSTL import tag.

Comment: Sorry, I totally overlooked that you was using `c:import` and somehow had in mind that it runs at the server side, not the client side. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks! How can I include this outputstream inside a div of my JSP? Should I write a JSP tag for this or is there a better way?

Comment: Use `<c:import>` the same way. Or if it is located at the same server, just use `<jsp:include>`.

Comment: Hmm, it seems I have to change the URL in the JSP! This is because the domain where the texts are included is different to the one where the web server is located. As such this servlet will act kind of as a proxy to the one where the text files reside. So, I will have to change the URL in the JSTL import tag to the {local web server}/{servlet path}, but that is still fine. Thanks!